# reactjs catch response from posted data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below code in node.js

```
app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {
  oauthClient
    .createToken(req.url)
    .then(function (authResponse) {
      oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null, 2);
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });

  res.send('');
});
```

and passing callback as below

> http://localhost:8000/authUri?json[clientId]=ABdfsdfsdcbLxxwU&json[clientSecret]=EiL8Cuasdsdfsdfl&json[environment]=sandbox&json[redirectUri]=http://localhost:8000/callback

The above code is working fine, But I want to implement this in react js functional component, like create a function and give the url, I tried the creating a function inside component say sample and gave the url like

**"/sample"**

But not working can someone please advise how to accomplish this

This is what I have done

> http://localhost:8000/authUri?json[clientId]=ABdfsdfsdcbLxxwU&json[clientSecret]=EiL8Cuasdsdfsdfl&json[environment]=sandbox&json[redirectUri]=http://localhost:3000/sample

```
useEffect((req,res) => {
    console.log(req);

},[])
```

I need to catch the data posted by third party

Please help, I am stuck here
Thanks,

Comment: How are you dealing with routing?

Comment: I have updated the route in app.js like sample/:callback?, and having url like /sample/callback, but the function is not getting invoked

Comment: The code in the question doesn't give us any information about that. How is `callback` used?

Comment: I have to pass this callback to a third party redirect back url

Comment: how can we help when the question doesn't include that code? please may you include all relevant code/information in the question?

Comment: It's simply bro adding redirect URL along with third party URL, there is no code for that

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to use react with express?

Comment: No, the above code is working with express, I want to just get data posted data from third party in my react component